# save mongoose model and submodel after populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find a way to simplify my backend logic and optimize my DB, for this it would be great if I could save a document and it's subdocuments all at once so that creating subdocuments becomes easier.

Here is a simple example:

the primary model:

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type : String},
  extrainfo: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Extrainfo'},
})
mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```

the subdocument:

```
var ExtrainfoSchema = new Schema({
  this: {type : String},
  that: {type: String},
})
mongoose.model('Extrainfo', ExtrainfoSchema);
```

how I hoped to be able to save:

```
Item.findOne({ name: 'whatever' }).populate('extrainfo').exec(function (err, item) {
  item.extrainfo.this = "something diferen" //some random change in subdocument
  item.save(function(){console.log("yay")}
});
```

Is there a way to do this whithout having to save to the document and the subdocument individually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this whithout having to save to the document and the subdocument individually ?

**No.** mongodb will write to one and only one collection during a given write operation, and mongoose doesn't have any feature as far as I know to provide a single-callback facility to write to multiple collections.

Comment: :( I hope this changes

Comment: but if I save the document after populate, will it replace the ref to the subdocument ? only if I populate with only a Schema.Types.ObjectId somehow right ?